# Get column wise data using regular expression

Tags: php, regex, perl

How to read column wise data using regular expression,I want to store these data into database so how to separate the columns.

```
 S/NO         INSULATED TANK SIZE          QTY        U.PRICE(Qr.)     TOTAL PRICE (Qr.)
        FW-50(S) (5 x 5 x 2 MH)
 01                                        1 SET        131,592.00            131,592.00
               w/p(3+2)
        FW-120(S) (10 x 6 x 2 MH) w/p
 02                                        1 SET        252,330.00            252,330.00
                  (5+5)
 03      FW-2(S) (1 x 2 x 1 MH) w/p (1+1)  1 SET        14,471.00             14,471.00
```

I have converted PDF into a text file using Linux command and I want to read data column wise then what should I do?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. We have ready to help you however we couldn't do your work unfortunately. Do you have tried anything in php or perl

Comment: This is csv document (tab delimit) or only space separated column?

Comment: Yes, I tried some regex to read those data from PDF but I am not able to read data from column INSULATED TANK SIZE and it's space separated column.

Comment: Is data of INSULATED TANK SIZE column in the same row as other columns?

Comment: Yes,It can be but in this case it is not in same row,I have to make it dynamic.

Comment: Please show *what you have tried* as well as the data structure that you want as output.

Comment: *"Yes,It can be but in this case it is not in same row, I have to make it dynamic"* The problem is that *only you* understands this data. All we can see is strings scattered about the page, with no way of knowing which ones belong together.

Answer (score 0):

Parsing OCR text output is an exercise in frustration and corner cases.  You need to actually implement a parser to deal with the different types of data you may encounter.  There is no good way to know that your parser is **CORRECT**, since you may be presented with more edge cases in the future, which makes the solution **Brittle** and potentially **Buggy**.

With that caveat out of the way, here is one way you might proceed:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;

use Data::Dumper;
$Data::Dumper::Sortkeys = 1;

my @fields;
my @extra_descriptions;
my @results;
open my $fh, "<input" or die "Unable to open 'input' : $!";
while( <$fh> ) {
    my @data;
    chomp();  # Remove newline
    s|^\s+||; # Remove leading spaces
    s|\s+$||; # Remove trailing spaces

    next unless m|\w|; # Skip empty lines

    @data = split/\s\s+/;  # Split on 2 or more spaces

    # Parse Header
    if ($. == 1) {
        @fields = @data;
        next;
    }

    if (1 == scalar @data) {
        # Extra Size Description
        push @extra_descriptions, shift @data;
        next;
    } elsif ( 4 == scalar @data or 5 == scalar @data ) {            
        my $sn = shift @data;
        my $desc = '';

        # Deal with possibly missing Size info
        if ( 4 == scalar @data ) {
            my $size = shift @data;
            $desc = join(', ', $size, @extra_descriptions);
        } else {
            # 3 columns, so missing Size info

            # Reverse because now main description is last
            $desc = join(', ', reverse @extra_descriptions); 
        }

        unshift(@data, $sn, $desc);

        # Data should be 5 columns
        (5 == scalar @data) or die "Something went wrong with data: " . join("\n",@data);

        # Size (description) should be column 1 ( second column )
        $data[1] =~ m|[FWx]| or die "Could not figure out size! $data[1]";

        my %row;
        my @field_names = qw( serialno size quantity unit_price total_price );
        for my $i ( 0 .. $#field_names ) {
            my $name = $field_names[$i];
            my $desc = $name . "_desc";
            $row{$name} = $data[$i];
            $row{$desc} = $fields[$i];
        }

        # TODO: Insert data into database here
        print Dumper(\%row);

        # Reset
        undef @extra_descriptions;

    } else {
        # Not 1, 4 or 5 columns
        die "Do not know what to do about this row: '$_'";
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
$VAR1 = {
          'quantity' => '1 SET',
          'quantity_desc' => 'QTY',
          'serialno' => '01',
          'serialno_desc' => 'S/NO',
          'size' => 'FW-50(S) (5 x 5 x 2 MH)',
          'size_desc' => 'INSULATED TANK SIZE',
          'total_price' => '131,592.00',
          'total_price_desc' => 'TOTAL PRICE (Qr.)',
          'unit_price' => '131,592.00',
          'unit_price_desc' => 'U.PRICE(Qr.)'
        };
$VAR1 = {
          'quantity' => '1 SET',
          'quantity_desc' => 'QTY',
          'serialno' => '02',
          'serialno_desc' => 'S/NO',
          'size' => 'FW-120(S) (10 x 6 x 2 MH) w/p, w/p(3+2)',
          'size_desc' => 'INSULATED TANK SIZE',
          'total_price' => '252,330.00',
          'total_price_desc' => 'TOTAL PRICE (Qr.)',
          'unit_price' => '252,330.00',
          'unit_price_desc' => 'U.PRICE(Qr.)'
        };
$VAR1 = {
          'quantity' => '1 SET',
          'quantity_desc' => 'QTY',
          'serialno' => '03',
          'serialno_desc' => 'S/NO',
          'size' => 'FW-2(S) (1 x 2 x 1 MH) w/p (1+1), (5+5)',
          'size_desc' => 'INSULATED TANK SIZE',
          'total_price' => '14,471.00',
          'total_price_desc' => 'TOTAL PRICE (Qr.)',
          'unit_price' => '14,471.00',
          'unit_price_desc' => 'U.PRICE(Qr.)'
        };
```